# tip of QTip2 tooltip incorrectly positioned

Tags: jquery, css, html, qtip2

I'm having difficulties with [QTip2](http://qtip2.com/) tooltips, the tip of the tooltip appears out of position, despite the `.qtip-tip` element having the `left: 50%; top: -8px` inline style applied correctly it doesn't seem to have an affect.

I have tried a dozen or so inline fixes and checked that all required classes are applied by comparing it to the [code listed on QTip2's website](http://qtip2.com/guides#style). The most annoying thing is that I'm sure I've faced & fixed this issue before, but this time around it's beaten me.

[image: shows how the tip on my (QTip2) tooltips appear out of position]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't beaten! somehow the `.qtip-tip` element lost it's absolute positioning, so I've added the following to my stylesheet.

```
.qtip-tip {
    position: absolute;
}
```